# Getting, "Missing required parameter Id" using Postman to Delete an Item in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS DynamoDB for the first time. I created a DynamoDB on AWS and I am able to GET and PUT using Postman.  I do not have the correct procedure to DELETE an item in the database using Postman. I get this error, "Missing required parameter Id".  This is my syntax for DELETE

```
{
    "Key": {
        "Id": {"N": "bbdeafc7-adc2-43eb-b357-2f6c27f33f43"}
    }

}
```

I get the Id from a GET request.

I also attempted:

```
{
    "Key": {
        "Id": {"S": "bbdeafc7-adc2-43eb-b357-2f6c27f33f43"}
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it correct data type? Number?

Comment: I tried "S" before and got the same error.

Comment: Clearly a UUID is a string, not a number. Neither of your examples shows TableName. Why? And are you using POST?

Comment: I am using DELETE. I did not need to pass the tablename for PUT and GET  The end point is to the DynamoDB table I think.

Comment: You can see the API at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html. You can't make *any* API call against a DynamoDB table without the table name. And it's an HTTP POST, according to the docs. I wasn't aware that DynamoDB has table-specific endpoints (maybe it does, I just wasn't aware, and I don't immediately see any docs on this).

Comment: @jarmod AWS documentation is fun. I can make GET and PUT calls to the DynamoDB but struggling on the syntax for the DELETE.

Comment: @jarmod I did add tablename with the same error, {
 "TableName": "abc-BlogTable-UMQ1LVBV386L",
 "Key": {
        "Id": {"S": "bbdeafc7-adc2-43eb-b357-2f6c27f33f43"}
    }
 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming **Id** is your partition key here. Do you have a sort key in your table? If yes, then you'll have to define both in the Key param to delete a single item. So, if your sort key is named **SK**, then the param will be:

```
{
"Key": {
    "Id":"bbdeafc7-adc2-43eb-b357-2f6c27f33f43",
    "SK": "abcd"
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not have a SK that I know of.  I am brand new to dynamodb. I found another video on youtube and I put in the id.

Comment: I do have a sort key. It was just not named SK

Comment: Yes @donotbea, a sort key can be named to anything. SK is just an example.